# Convert RGB to Hex C++?

Tags: c++, colors, rgb

I am looking for a simple C++ function that takes three integers as r, g, and b and returns the corresponding hex color code as an integer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
int hexcolor(int r, int g, int b)
{
    return (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b;
}
```

Of course you'll need some output formatting to show it as hex.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned long rgb = (r<<16)|(g<<8)|b;
```

given that r,g,b are unsigned 8bit chars.
(That´s really easy, and Google would´ve helped.)

Answer (score 0):

I got on this page because I needed R, G, B converted to a valid Hex string (*Hex color code*) for use within an HTML document. It took me some time to get it right, so putting it here as reference for others (*and my future self*).

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

//unsigned char signature ensures that any input above 255 gets automatically truncated to be between 0 and 255 appropriately (e.g. 256 becomes 0)

std::string rgbToHex(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b) {
    std::stringstream hexSS;
    std::stringstream outSS;
    //setw(6) is setting the width of hexSS as 6 characters. setfill('0') fills any empty characters with 0. std::hex is setting the format of the stream as hexadecimal
    hexSS << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(6) << std::hex;
    //r<<16 left shifts r value by 16 bits. For the complete expression first 8 bits are represented by r, then next 8 by g, and last 8 by b.
    hexSS << (r<<16 | g<<8 | b);
    outSS << "#" << hexSS.str();
    return outSS.str();
}
```